# Get number of posts by a user (draft, pending review & published)

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to get the number of posts by a user including all post status (draft, pending review & published).

This will be used for a rule. If a user has more than or equal to **X** number of posts on a post type, they will see a customized text.

Found the following but that only counts the published posts.

```
$userID = get_current_user_id();
echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( $userID , "books"  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds very simple as querying for posts and iterating through the results and working with the post status.. Just make sure to add `'post_status' => 'any'` to the query args so as to include more statuses beside the published:

```
$args = array(
    'author' => 1, // user ID here
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // retrieve all
    'post_type' => 'post', // post type (change to your PT)
    'post_status' => 'any' // any status
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

$drafts = $pendings = $published = array();

if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) :;

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        switch ( $post->post_status ) {
            case 'draft':
                $drafts[] = $post;
                break;
            case 'pending':
                $pendings[] = $post;
                break;
            case 'published':
                $published[] = $post;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

endif;

echo var_dump( 'drafts', $drafts, 'pending', $pendings, 'published', $published ); // or print_r
```

Hope that helps.

> This will be used for a rule. If a user has more than or equal to X
>   number of posts on a post type, they will see a customized text.

An example usage: `if ( count( $drafts ) >= (int) X ) { # Hey!! }`